# What are the exact steps for setting up file sharing between ubuntu computers?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I know there are a ton of "help guides," and I have spent hours trying them all. Nothing works.

Here is my situation. I have Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 12.04. Both are connected to the same router and have static 192.168. addresses. I would like to create a folder in the 15.04 home directory and put files to be shared there. Then, using the 12.04 computer, I would like to manipulate those files.

How exactly do I set this up?

- what do I need to install?
- what do I need to do to the ufw enabled firewalls?
- what exactly am I typing into "Connect to Server?"
- when I try `nautilus-share` and "share this folder" and go to Browse Network, all I ever see is "Windows Network". But I don't have any Windows computers in my network.
- I have tried installing `openssh-server` on 15.04 and "share this folder" etc, but nothing ever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Browse to the folder you want to share in Nautilus on the 15.04 machine
2. Right click on Properties
3. Click on the Local Network Share tab
4. Tick "Share this folder"
5. Tick "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder"
6. Tick "Guest access"
7. Close all, reboot both computers
8. On the 12.04 computer, open a Nautilus window and type Control-L
9. In the box that opens at the top, type (no quotes) "smb://192.168.[rest of 15.04 machine's URL]"
10. The folder you shared should be displayed in Nautilus

If any steps do not work, reply back with exact details.  Some assumptions about your configuration have been made, that may need to be corrected.

Comment: Addition: Get the IP from `ifconfig`, if unknown.

Comment: Thanks. I select Type: Windows share. then did as you say with the smb: part. "Failed to retrieve share list from server." Do you know how to retrieve this list?

Comment: Where is this "type: windows share" option found?

Comment: In 15.04, the "interface" is different than on 12.04. In 12.04 there is a dropdown. Looks similar to here (except I selected "Windows share" under #3 where it says service type--as some online guides said to: http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/114). When I select Connect to Server this interface appears in 12.04.

Comment: You stated that the folder you wanted to share was on the 15.04 machine, not the 12.04 machine, so I don't understand why you are changing folder settings on the 12.04 machine.  I did not say anything in my instructions about selecting Connect to Server.  Please execute only the instructions given exactly and report back if things do not work.  Adding extra steps only introduces confusion.

Comment: Step 8: on the 12.04 machine, open Nautilus and type control L.... (this is the same as selecting Connect to Server. I did both and it gets the same error message).

Comment: Next step is to disable ufw firewall on both machines and retry.

Comment: Sorry for extra step organic. I did just as you said. After typing control-L and smb://192. etc, I get an error message about the unable to retrieve share list from server.

Comment: this worked. do you know what port I need to allow to make this work with ufw enabled?

Comment: Not off top of my head.  I seem to remember there are 3 or 4.  Should be easy to google.  You are almost there!  edit: some say use command `sudo ufw allow samba`

Comment: I'm looking for "best" consensus.

Comment: Ports: 137-139,445. Thanks Organic!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got it working.